# PHP strtotime returning always midnight

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I'm having a weird problem. When I do strtotime it's not considering the hours part of the original date, and it's always returning midnight. I tried to research but I couldn't find anything specific.

Is there something I'm missing?

```
$original_date = "2015-08-07 02:00:00";
$next_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("monday this Week +1 week", strtotime($original_date)));
```

It returns `$next_date` as `2015-08-14 00:00:00`

Comment: I'm not sure how to correct it, but giving `strtotime` a specific day like Monday sets it to Monday 00:00:00 and then the other calculations use that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, add time which you want to retrieve in next date,.

```
$original_date = "2015-08-07 02:00:00";
echo $next_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("monday this Week 02:00:00 +1 week", strtotime($original_date)));
```

Comment: actually when saying monday this week, it will take date only and add 00:00:00 mid night internally, so we have just added time in the strtotime.

Comment: This works! Would you advice to always add the hour as a security blanket?

Comment: @Kitara yes you should always add it when you want to retain your hours, mins and secs.

Answer (score 3):

`monday this week +1 week` assumes you’re looking for midnight of the monday of the week of the passed in time. If you want to preserve the hours part of the time, then you can append it to your `date` format because it should always be the same as in `$original_date`

```
date('Y-m-d ' . date('H:i:s', strtotime($original_date)), strtotime("monday this Week +1 week", strtotime($original_date)));
```

Comment: Hi, it didn't work for me output was 2015-08-10 19:33:35. I modify to date('Y-m-d', strtotime("monday this Week +1 week", strtotime($original_date))).' '.date('H:i:s', strtotime($original_date)) and it worked.

Comment: @Kitara that works too, I was missing the `strtotime` call

Answer (score 3):

When you use `monday` in `strtotime` you're resetting the time back to 00:00:00. You will have to explicitly pass the time in either your `date` or `strtotime` to get your desired behavior. See [this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055935/php-get-next-occurrence-of-monday-from-a-certain-date-with-time) for a similar issue.

```
$next_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("monday this Week +1 week " . date('H:i:s', strtotime($original_date)), strtotime($original_date)))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$date = strtotime('2018-08-14 02:00:00');
$next_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("monday this Week 02:00:00 +1 week", $date)); // 2018-08-20 02:00:00
```